# How do you update the screen after you change the text with a setText in android?

Tags: android

How do you update the screen after you change the text with a setText..

Code:

```
TextView settings_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_settings);
        settings_text.setText(Strings.SETTINGS);    


TextView terms_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_terms);
         terms_text.setText(Strings.TERMS);

TextView about_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_aboutus);
         about_text.setText(Strings.ABOUT);

Intent intent = new Intent(Language.this,MenuScreen.class);     
            startActivity(intent);  
    finish();
```

Problem:
 After this The values are not reflecting on the screen

Suggest me..Thank you

Comment: Simple remove startActivity() and finsih() code then you know value is change or not.

Comment: You are finishing the activity you set this text in.

Comment: Actual problem is: For the First time Time the values are not reflecting..but from the second time on wards i.e if i go to another screen and again coming to the modified screen..at this time the content is getting modified..

Comment: @santoshkaradla,Values are reflecting first time also but before you seen values you redirect to another activity so i think you have to implement handler which will delay to call your second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay to start second activity :

```
import android.os.Handler;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Language.this,MenuScreen.class);     
       startActivity(intent);  
    }
},5000); // 5000 is represent time to delay execute code under run().
```

Comment: Actually i have done in a different way based on your first comment..after setting the text values i am giving an alert dialog message in which i am redirecting the screen to main screen and resulting in the change of values..

Comment: Awesome buddy..Your answer works..But The problem is only with the delay..but not a matter!!

Comment: You can change 5000 value as per your requirement here 5000 represent 5 second so you reduce this time with 3000 or 2000.

Answer (score 0):

1st way:

Using alert Dialog

```
 TextView terms_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_terms);
     terms_text.setText(Strings.TERMS);
```

TextView about_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_aboutus);
     about_text.setText(Strings.ABOUT);

```
 TextView contactus_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contactus);
 contactus_text.setText(Strings.CONTACT_US);
```

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Language.this);

```
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Language changed successfully");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Continue",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Language.this,MenuScreen.class);                                                             startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

}
```

});

alertDialog.show();

2nd way:using POSTDELAYED METHOD

TextView terms_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_terms);
         terms_text.setText(Strings.TERMS);

TextView about_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_aboutus);
     about_text.setText(Strings.ABOUT);

```
 TextView contactus_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contactus);
 contactus_text.setText(Strings.CONTACT_US);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
               Intent intent = new Intent(Language.this,MenuScreen.class);     
                                           startActivity(intent);  
                                        }
                                    },100);
```